# CSS Lint, heading redefines, and factoring code

Tags: css, structure

CSSLint warns me about redefining headers (although why JUST headers?)

I write a lot of my CSS in this manner:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-variant:small-caps;
    }

h1  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0 0 0;
    /*  text-align:left;    */
    }

    h1:first-letter {
        position: relative;
        top: 0.5em;
        font-size: 140%;
        }

h2  {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    }

h3  {
    margin: 0.85em 0 0.3em 0;
    font-size: 1.72em;
    }

h4  {
    margin:0;
    padding: .72em 0 0.2em 0;
    font-size: 1.44em;
    }
```

Is this considered bad form?

My thought when muddling my way through this, was:  When I want to change the look, I want to enter it in the fewest number of places possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning is described at the [CSS Lint Wiki](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Headings-should-only-be-defined-once) and [Don’t Style Headings Using HTML5 Sections](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2011/09/06/style-headings-using-html5-sections/) (*This describes a bad use of restyling the same heading tags for different uses*).

In your case where you just split some properties to avoid repeating them, you should not worry.

So you can safely ignore this warning for this kind of usage.

Comment: Thank you.  I did read that section, and it seemed arbitrary.  Indeed enough of the CSSLint recommendations are arbitrary that I take them all with a grain of salt.